# MYSQL online members in past 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get the number of members who have logged in, in the past 30 days using the column "lastOnline" in the format of 1274147184, from my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
count(*) as users 
from table 
where from_unixtime(lastonline) >= now() - interval 30 day
```

Comment: Sounds right assuming there is one record in the table for each time a user logs in.  It may be worth adding an index to the table for the field 'lastOnline' if there is not already one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lastOnline > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()) - (3600*24*30));
```